# Commercial Java LIB / API to read and write Word 2007 docs

Tags: java, ms-word

I need a simple to use / good docs / good support java lib to read and write word documents, namely word 2007 support (and word 2010 support planned).

As the project I'm in has budget and time-constraints I don't mind buying a commercial lib :) I know they are XML files in a somewhat open format but I really don't want to waste time understanding the XML specification.

Any good recommendations from happy customers?

(Right now my choice is going to Aspose.Words for Java)

Answer (score 0):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I used Apache POI. Don't know about word documents, but I had absolutely no problem with Excel, both with reading and writing.

http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Right now I only need word 2007 / 2010 support. Apache POI doesn't seem to be currently up-to-date (HWPF is orphaned with no leader :))

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which is based on the OpenOffice capabilities for importing and exporting documents of various formats.  Docmosis will let you populate documents word documents, but does that cover your "read" requirement?

Answer (score 0):

[docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html) will help.  Hard to do anything meaningful with any of the suggested APIs without a rudimentary understanding of the file format though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site http://poi.apache.org/index.html .

For Word we have the HWPF and XWPF library .